# A system of 1st-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve $\begin{aligned} \dfrac{dx}{dt} &= -2 x - 6 y \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} &= x - 7 y \end{aligned}$.

Let $P = \begin{bmatrix}-2&-6\\1&-7\end{bmatrix}$. My approach is to take $\operatorname{det}(P - \lambda I) =0 \implies \lambda = - 5 \vee -4$.

So then I get $\left[\begin{array}{c}
2\cr
1
\end{array}\right]$ as an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = -5$ and $ \left[\begin{array}{c}
3\cr
1
\end{array}\right]$ as an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = -4$.

So it seems to me that a solution should be: 
$\begin{aligned} x_1 = A2e^{-5t}+3Be^{-4t} \\ x_2 = Ae^{-5t}+Be^{-4t}\end{aligned}$ however this is apparently incorrect. Any help anyone can give on where I went wrong is appreciated.

Comment: What are $x_1,x_2$ ?

Comment: $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = y$ I believe. However, the question does not state it. All it is says is ``Find the general solution in the form $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$. Use A and B to denote arbitrary constants. Fill in both blanks before submitting."

Comment: You should probably define what $P$ is in your post. I assume it is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-2&-6\\1&-7\end{bmatrix}$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes. That is my matrix P.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether why do you think that your solution is incorrect?

Comment: It seems like a very bad sort of question for an online solution checker. There are infinite equivalent ways of describing the general solution to an ODE, so unless the software is somewhat sophisticated, it probably can't detect these.

Answer (score 1):

From second equation
$$x=y'+7y$$
derive it to get
$$x'=y''+7y'$$
substitute in equ.1
$$y''+7y'=-2(y'+7y)-6y$$
$$y''+9y'+20y=0$$
the general solution is
$$y=Ae^{-5t}+Be^{-4t}$$
now derive this equation and substitute in equ 2 to get
$$x=2Ae^{-5t}+3Be^{-4t}$$

Comment: Isn't this merely reproducing a part of the question?

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is an $e$ missing in $x_2$ (that is, in the solution for $y$). If you take $x_2=Ae^{-5t}+Be^{-4t}$, your solution is correct. Just derive both soolutions and check that they satisfy the system.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That was not the issue as it's still wrong. I had just typed it incorrectly into math stackexchange but typed it properly in my WebWork system and it was still wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong. Just take $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$ and check that they satisfy the system.